# import and use d3.parseCsv version 5

Tags: csv, d3.js

I'm trying to use `d3.csv.parse(string)` as documented https://d3-wiki.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/master/CSV/#parse

I've installed `"d3": "5.12.0"` but I find that with

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
d3.csv.parse
```

is undefined. What version of `d3` do those docs cover?

After some searching I find https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv and `d3.csvParse` but this doesn't work as I'm expecting.

```
const c = "Name,Count,Total Area\nFoo,6.0,0.13\nBar,8.0,0.24"
d3.csvParse(c, data => console.log(data))
```

I was expecting an array of objects, but instead I just get the first object

```
{Count: "6.0", Name: "Foo", Total Area: "0.13"}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here,
 Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

OK, so it seems that `d3.csvParse()` doesn't behave like `d3.csv()` and the second function argument is not a callback
https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv/blob/v1.1.1/README.md#dsv_parse

```
console.log( d3.csvParse(c))

[0: {Name: "Foo", Count: "6.0", Total Area: "0.13"}
1: {Name: "Bar", Count: "8.0", Total Area: "0.24"}]
```

Sorry for the noise!